# Firebase undefined error

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having problem with sending null data to Firebase and I'm getting this error message:

> Runtime Error
>   Reference.update failed: First argument contains undefined in property

I have:

```
   public save(url: string, params: any) {
        return this.af.database.ref('alunos').push().set(params);
    }
```

as params i'm sending:

```
    this.aluno = {
            bairro: '',
            celular: '',
            cep: '',
            cidade: '',
            cpf: '',
            dataNascimento: '',
            email: '',
            nome: '',
            numero: null,
            rg: '',
            rua: '',
            ativo: true,
            genero: null,
            telefone: '',
            uf: ''
        };
```

I already know that the Firebase does not accept undefined but i'm using null, so this shouldn't happen right ? Any way to resolve this without changing the data structure like to string?

Comment: Are you able to share what you're trying to post to firebase so we can get a better understanding of the issue.

You can pass `null` without issue.

Comment: There you go, i hope you undestand.

Comment: Are you working with `angularfire2`? Is this a valid command; `return this.af.database.ref('alunos').push().set(params);` Shouldn't it be `this.af.list('alunos').push(params);`?

Comment: @sketchthat i'm working with ionic, this.af.database.ref('alunos').push().set(params); was wrong way, now i'm using this.af.database.ref('alunos').push(params); should i use list('alunos')? it makes any difference?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't seen the documentation for for `ref`. Using `list` will generate unique keys for your database writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `null` to a `set` command.

`set` will create a new object. It's not used for updating an existing object.

Therefore null isn't needed, as it's ignored when creating. You should remove `numero` and `genero` from your object.

```
this.aluno = {
  bairro: '',
  celular: '',
  cep: '',
  cidade: '',
  cpf: '',
  dataNascimento: '',
  email: '',
  nome: '',
  rg: '',
  rua: '',
  ativo: true,
  telefone: '',
  uf: ''
};
```

If you want to update an existing object then `null` is accepted when you make the command `this.af.database.ref('alunos').update(params);`

Have a read of the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) for more information on the differences between `set` and `update`.